# What's the next number in the list?

Tags: number-sequence

What's the next number?

> 8, 20, 40, 68, 104, 122, 170, 226, 290, 362, 442

***EDIT*** (since we already have some answers below which assumed the next number correctly) ... For the record, here are some further numbers in the sequence:

> 530, 626, 730, 842, 962, 1090, 1226

Comment: @Rubio The problem is that now I myself forgot how I constructed the sequence.

Comment: Well - that's not ideal, is it! The latest answer seems to be *a* complete solution, even if perhaps not your intended solution; if there's a reason it's not a fitting answer, I don't see it - is there a reason not to accept it?

Comment: I meant [shoover's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/67104).

Comment: @Rubio I didn't check if that works out for all of the numbers stated. Did you?

Comment: Yes; it fits the original pattern and the hint exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generating expression for your sequence is

> $(2x-\lfloor\log_{10}(2x-1)\rfloor)^2 + (2-\lfloor\log_{10}(2x-1)\rfloor)^2$ for $x\in\Bbb{Z^+}$

You've given the values for $x=1,\ldots,18$, which gives the next elements as

> $1370, 1522, 1682, 1850, 2026, \ldots$

for $x=19,\ldots,23$ on up to

> $9410, 9802, 10000, 10404, 10816, \ldots$

for $x=49,\ldots,53$ and beyond.

But that doesn't make for a very satisfying puzzle, so I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Next number could be

> 530 (Which is square of 23 plus 1)

As,

> the first 5 numbers were obtained by adding 4 to the squares of even numbers- 2,4,6,8 and 10.

Then,

> 1 is getting added to the squares of odd numbers - 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21. So the next number could be square of 23  that is 529 and 1 added to it.

Comment: Not bad, but there is a more elegant way, which doesn't discriminate between the first five numbers and the remaining numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is

> 530

Because

> the difference increases by 8 each time

although that breaks down for

> 104, 122, 170 - so unless that's a mistake my answer is wrong